# Why does Dataframe.to_sql() slow down after certain amount of rows?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a very large  `Pandas` Dataframe ~9 million records, 56 columns, which I'm trying to load into a MSSQL table, using `Dataframe.to_sql()`. Importing the whole Dataframe in one statement often leads to errors, relating to memory.

To cope with this, I'm looping through the Dataframe in batches of 100K rows, and importing a batch at a time. This way I no longer get any errors, but the code slows down dramatically after about 5.8 million records. The code I'm using:

```
maxrow = df.shape[0]
stepsize = 100000
for i in range(0, maxrow, stepsize):
    batchstart = datetime.datetime.now()
        
    if i == 0:
        if_exists = 'replace'
            
    else:
        if_exists = 'append'
        
    df_import = df.iloc[i:i+stepsize]
        
    df_import.to_sql('tablename', 
                    engine,
                    schema='tmp',
                    if_exists=if_exists,
                    index=False,
                    dtype=dtypes
                    )
```

I've timed the batches, and there is a clear breaking point in speed:
[image: Times per 200K rows]
These results are basically the same for batches of 50k, 100k and 200k rows. it takes about 40 minutes to upload 6 million records, and another 2 hours and 20 minutes to upload the next 3 million.

My thinking was that it was either due to the size of the MSSQL table, or something being cached/saved after each upload. Because of that I've tried pushing the Dataframe to two different tables. I've also tried something like `expunge_all()` on the `SQLALchemy session`, after each upload. Both to no effect.

Manually stopping imports after 5 million records and restarting from 5 million with a new engine object also hasn't helped.

I'm all out of ideas what might be the cause of the process slowing down so drastically, and would really appreciate help.

**UPDATE**

As a last resort I've reversed the loop, uploading parts of the Dataframe starting at the highest index, looping down.

This has basically reversed the times per batch. So it seems it is the data itself that is different/bigger further down the Dataframe. Not the connection being overloaded or the SQL table getting to large.

[image: Batchtimes including reverse loop]

Thanks to everyone trying to help, but it seems I need to go through the data to see what causes this.

Comment: Have you tried simply using the `chunksize=` argument of `.to_sql()` to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: can you add some details about SQL Server? (select @@version, is it on-prem, azure sql database, etc?)   schema of destination table, including any index definitions.  across different runs, are you deleting/reloading into the same table, or different tables?

Comment: What are the data types in the DataFrame and what are the data types of the columns it creates in the destination SQL Server table? The worst outcomes would be if it creates `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` columns in the table because of the extra LOB (Large OBject) storage management overhead that adds.

Comment: @GordThompson: Yes, that was the first thing I tried, before creating my own loop. This however failed most of the time, due to memory errors or my vpn connection (which I use to connect to the MSSQL server) being shutdown. It has worked one time, but took nearly seven hours to complete.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It does create quite a few `varchar(max)` columns. I've explicitly given it SQLAlchemy datatypes, and have not added length restrictions to columns for which I don't know the maximum length.

Comment: @StrayCatDBA I think it's an on-premises server, to which I can connect after activating a VPN connection. @@version gives me `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU22-GDR) (KB5029378) - 15.0.4326.1 (X64) `. There are no index definitions on the table. The first iteration of the loop, replaces the existing table, runs after that append to the newly created table.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: I've now tried limiting the size of every `varchar` column by giving it a maximum size. This has not made a difference to the tim taken for each batch.